# How to implement smooth infinite automatic scrolling on an infinitely long webpage?

Tags: javascript, scroll, setinterval, infinite-scroll, requestanimationframe

I have an infinitely long webpage (it loads new chunks in when the page gets *x* distance from the bottom). I want to implement, via Javascript, smooth automatic scrolling of this webpage in a way that minimizes jitter/jumpiness.

I've tried two primary methods: `setInterval()` and `requestAnimationFrame()`. So far, `setInterval()` seems to give the best visual performance, though I'm limited in speed (at least on Chrome) as intervals below approximately 50ms appear to floor at ~50 (and jumping more than a few pixels each "frame" produces visual artifacts). `requestAnimationFrame()` works ok most of the time, but has some occasional jumps and jitters.

Code for the two methods I've tried are below. Are there other methods (or tweaks) I should try? What's the best way to accomplish this?

`setInterval() method`:

```
let html;

window.onload = function() {
  html = document.documentElement;

  setInterval(function() {
    let scrollTop = Math.round(html.scrollTop);
    let increment = 2;
    html.scrollTop += increment;
  }, 16);
};
```

`requestAnimationFrame()` method (based on [this post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/?utm_source=pocket_mylist) from a Chrome developer):

```
function animationInterval(ms, signal, callback) {
  const start = document.timeline.currentTime;

  function frame(time) {
    if (signal.aborted) return;
    callback(time);
    scheduleFrame(time);
  }

  function scheduleFrame(time) {
    const elapsed = time - start;
    const roundedElapsed = Math.round(elapsed / ms) * ms;
    const targetNext = start + roundedElapsed + ms;
    const delay = targetNext - performance.now();
    setTimeout(() => requestAnimationFrame(frame), delay);
  }

  scheduleFrame(start);
}

const controller = new AbortController();

animationInterval(20, controller.signal, time => {
  let scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  let increment = 2;
  html.scrollTop += increment;
});
```

Comment: `smooth automatic scrolling of this webpage in a way that minimizes jitter/jumpiness.` scroll where? to the bottom? to the top?

Comment: can't you use native ways of doing it? like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia a slow, endless scroll, as if someone was slowly but consistently scrolling the page. so it's not trying to scroll to, say, an anchor, but just forever scrolling down.

Comment: as for `scrollIntoView()`, if I were to use that (for, say, scrolling to each new item on the page as it chunks in), then the scroll would be stop/start/stop/start/etc. I want a consistent, linear, downward motion.